# Matlab, how to write two number variables into single string cell array variable?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have two number variables of size <5x1>

```
    X = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]';
    Y = [-1, -2, 4.5, 12.6, -5]';
```

and I would like to write a variable string cell array <5x1 cell> using these X and Y variables with output as

```
'     1,-1,'
'     2,-2,'
'     3,4.5,'
'     4,12.6,'
'     5,-5'
```

Any help will be appreciative. Thanks

Comment: Do you need that whitespace pre-appended to all cells? And the last cell has just one `comma sign` while others have two?

Comment: In addition to @Divakar's question: [What do you need that cell of stings for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I need whitespace pre-appended to all cells and last cell should have one comma sign only. I need this particular format to feed into specific software. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the most intuitive and fastest way:

```
%# example data
X = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]';
Y = [-1, -2, 4.5, 12.6, -5]';

%# Controls the amount of leading spaces. This may depend on your specific 
%# software (or hardware?) so I left it here as a seperate variable.
spaces = {repmat(' ', 1,5)};  %# NOTE: must be cell to protect it from trim()

%# Now form the cellstring
S = strcat(spaces, num2str(X), ',', num2str(Y, '%-g'), ',');

%# complete it by removing the last comma
S{end} = S{end}(1:end-1);
```

Comment: Thanks, however the final 'ans' is <1x1 cell> and not in the right format.

Comment: +1 ,I was trying to implement this but was stuck thinking a way around the trimming. Nice answer

Comment: @user3771510 on my machine the final answer is a `5x1` cell exactly same to the one in the question.I have tested it on R2014a and R2011a

Comment: @user3771510: same here; I tested on R2010a/b, R2012a, R2013b. What's your version?

Comment: @user3771510: do you need "integers" to be integers? I mean, this solution uses 2 digits always, even for elements where `round(N)==N`; is that acceptable, or should extra digits be included only when necessary?

Comment: Thanks, now I got it right. it is 5x1 cell array. Thanks a lot

Comment: second one could be `num2str(Y, '%g')` as it uses as few '0's as possible, therefore `12.6` would be `12.6` and `-2` would be `-2`

Comment: @brechmos: thanks, that's what I was wondering about. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Rody, in the format the extra digits only should be included when needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach based on `arrayfun` -

```
%// Inputs
X = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
Y = [-1, -2, 4.5, 12.6, -5]'

t1 = arrayfun(@(k) strcat(num2str(X(k)),',',num2str(Y(k)),','),[1:numel(X)]','uni',0)
out = strcat({'     '},t1)
last_ele = char(out(end))
out(end) = {last_ele(1:end-1)} %// out is the desired output
```

Output -

```
out = 
    '     1,-1,'
    '     2,-2,'
    '     3,4.5,'
    '     4,12.6,'
    '     5,-5'
```

Comment: why not use `t1 = arrayfun(@(k) strcat('     ',num2str(X(k)),',',num2str(Y(k)),','),[1:numel(X)]','uni',0)` instead of writing it in two lines ?

Comment: @Nishant I guess I didn't want to cramp in all in one line. Oh btw that way of `whitespace` concatenation won't work with `strcat`.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a better way than looping but this should work:

```
X = [1:5]';
Y = [-1, -2, 4.6, 12.6, -5]';
XY = [X Y];

C = cell( size(XY, 1), 1);
for ii=1:size(XY, 1)
        C{ii} = sprintf('     %d,%g', XY(ii,:) );

        if( ii ~= length(XY) )
               C{ii} = [C{ii} ','];
        end

end

C
```

Comment: @Divakar's arrayfun below is probably a better solution or some combination.  The fewer loops the better off you are :-)

Comment: I am now down to, "My answer above is *an* answer, but not near as efficient as the others" :-)

Comment: If it gets the desired output, it's worth it! +1 for efforts.

Comment: Maybe you need a correction for the pre-allocation - `C = cell(size(XY,1),1)`